# How to add external css and javascript file in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I am facing problem adding external css and javascript file in my view file. I have created separate directory for CSS and Javascript. Currently my directory looks like:

- config
- controller

  - AdminTabs.php
- CSS

  - tab_v.css
- Javascript

  - tab_v.js
- models
- views

  - admin

    - tab_v.php

I have included the files in view tab_v.php like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/tab_v.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="../Javascript/tab_v.js"></script>
```

tab_v.php is loaded by the controller AdminTabs.php
I get error:

```
  domainname/app/CSS/tab_v.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  domainname/app/JavaScript/tab_v.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: You should create a assets folder out side of application folder.

Comment: Can you show an example how the path will look like if I create a folder?

Comment: Added answer should help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First load the url helper application > config > autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

> And then set your base url in application > config > config.php if not css links and js may
>   not work

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname/';
```

if on hosting url look like something

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';
```

Directory

```
application

assets

assets > css > tab_v.css

assets > js > tab_v.js

system

index.php
```

Head

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/tab_v.css');?>">
<script type='text/javascript' src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/tab_v.js');?>"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer